# mysql remove char in nth position

Tags: mysql

I need to remove 3rd hyphen(-) or the last hyphen from every records on my table.
this is the sample data

> 2009-12245-5432112310000-4
>
> 2009-12245-5431212320000-
>
> 2009-12245-H196812310000-
>
> 2009-12245-C026512310000-0

Output should be like this after UPDATE

> 2009-12245-54321123100004
>
> 2009-12245-5431212320000
>
> 2009-12245-H196812310000
>
> 2009-12245-C0265123100000

Is there any mysql function can I used together with UPDATE command? I know replace() command but I think it has no parameter for specific position of char to replace.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use combination of `CONCAT()` and `SUBSTRING_INDEX()`. Try below query:

```
UPDATE tblName
SET column = CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(column,'-',3),SUBSTRING_INDEX(column,'-',-1));
```

It will concatenate first substring and last substring. Below is the output:

```
+---------------------------+
| 2009-12245-54321123100004 |
| 2009-12245-5431212320000  |
| 2009-12245-H196812310000  |
| 2009-12245-C0265123100000 |
+---------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Use 2 `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to achieve this.
First `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to get the string before last `-` and
second `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to get the string after last `-`.

[Read more about SUBSTRING_INDEX here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

**Query**

```
update tblName
set str=concat(substring_index(str,'-',3),substring_index(str,'-',-1));
```

[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b7e36/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `column` = CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`column`, '-', 3), SUBSTRING_INDEX(`column`, '-', -1));
```

Comment: I already checked that, If I used that, the last digit will vanish also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `RIGHT` and `LEFT` function with the `REPLACE` and `CONCAT` function:

```
UPDATE TABLE SET column = CONCAT(LEFT(column, CHAR_LENGTH(column)-4), 
                                 REPLACE(RIGHT(col, 4), '-', ''));
```

The [RIGHT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_right) function

> Returns the rightmost len characters from the string str, or NULL if
>   any argument is NULL.

The [LEFT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left) function

> Returns the leftmost len characters from the string str, or NULL if any 
>   argument is NULL.

So you take the string and get the last 4 digits via the RIGHT function and put these substring into the replace function. With the REPLACE function you remove the `-`. After that you concat the `LEFT` string with the new string.